# Raspberry Pi4B+ Access able over LAN but has intermittent internet access

Tags: networking

As above, I'm able to SSH and VNC into the box without any issues (lag, packet loss) on the local network, however it seems to have intermittant internet access. If at all.

I thought this was a duplicate IP problem but even running a fresh install of Dietpi, with WiFi disabled over Ethernet using DHCP, still gives intermittant internet.

Edit: I'm beginnging to think this is a hardware fault, as I notice my external drive intermittant dropping without being disconnected. I'd be interested to see why I have LAN but not internet access.

Comment: Do you get the same problem with the latest Raspbian Buster fully updated?

Comment: Hello and welcome – Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question. – Also, you should add more information about what exactly "intermittent internet access" means in this situation.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with your internet router but not with the local network.

Comment: Yup, the OS stopped updating about two weeks ago, so it's as updated as it can be considering APT can't resolve the necessary URLs to actually update anything. I downloaded and flashed the latest Dietpi onto a new SD card and had exactly the same issue, which leads me to believe it's hardware.

Comment: In terms of defining intermittant internet access, the box is able to access the internet randomly, or not at all. Sorry I can't give an exact spreadsheet breakdown on that. As mentioned, of noting is that my external drive also disconnects intermittantly. Also worth noting is that my heatsink+fan covers the Pi and touches the WiFi chip and CPU only, so I'm wondering whether the disconnection issues are somehow related to an overheating bus issue. However that still wouldn't explain how I can VNC over the network and yet not have internet access.

Comment: In terms of the setup, it's a fibre router, giving internet to a wired+wifi switch, which then feeds to my LAN. I havnt had an issue on any of the other devices, only this one. The problem seemed to coincide with installing PiHole, though it could be unrelated. The reinstall action of a new OS yesterday debunks that theory, as surely PiHole wouldn't make any permanant changes to the Pi Bootloader. Also, if I had set a static IP on the router, that wouldn't have any noticible effect upon a new OS.